# Миграция базы на Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

Есть приложение на ruby on rails

schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170302072830) do

create_table "stocks", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name",       null: false
  t.integer  "unit_price", null: false
  t.integer  "interest",   null: false
  t.integer  "duration",   null: false
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_stocks_on_user_id", using: :btree
end

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "email",               default: "", null: false
  t.string   "encrypted_password",  default: "", null: false
  t.string   "username",            default: "", null: false
  t.datetime "remember_created_at"
  t.integer  "sign_in_count",       default: 0,  null: false
  t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
  t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
  t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
  t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
  t.datetime "created_at",                       null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                       null: false
  t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
end
end
```

При разработке было несколько миграций

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Делаю миграцию на Heroku heroku rake db:migrate

получаю лог

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А что ни так с полем duration и его типом integer? Там было изменение типа с date на integer.

> ALTER TABLE "stocks" ALTER COLUMN "duration" TYPE integer
>   PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  column "duration" cannot be cast automatically to type integer

Ну и его подсказка мне ни о чем не говорит

> HINT:  You might need to specify "USING duration::integer".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ваше изменение типа может потенциально привести к потере данных**. PostgreSQL делает *неявно* только те преобразования, которые к потерям не приводят, но вы переходите к более "узкому" типу, поэтому как преобразовывать существующие значения, придётся указать *явно*. Это такая мера предосторожности, чтобы вы лёгким взмахом не убили собственные данные.

Постгрес вам даже подсказал, как можно исправить команду изменения колонки на уровне языка постгреса, вам оставалось только перевести этот совет в синтаксис рельсомиграций:

```
change_column :stocks, :duration, "integer USING duration::integer"
#                    явное преобразование  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно из за того, что в разных миграциях одни и те же поля у меня имели разный тип данных происходила эта ошибка.

Правильно было бы при новых миграциях не менять тип поля, а удалять его и создавать новое.

В моем случае я полностью удалил старые миграции, создал новую где указал все таблици с уже верными данными и это решило проблему.

Comment: *Правильно было бы при новых миграциях не менять тип поля, а удалять его и создавать новое.* -- нет, неправильно. Можно было изменить и существующее, не теряя данных.

Comment: Окей, теряя, но те, которые вам, судя по типам, и не нужны. Описал, что было *правильно* сделать, в соседнем ответе.

Comment: Возможно, но я на тот момент не знал можно ли менять старые миграции, повлияет ли это как то на работу приложения. Тепрь знаю несколько способов )

Comment: Миграции нельзя менять лишь те, которые уже выполнились на важных базах. У вас важная база, как я понимаю, только на хероку :)

Comment: У меня учебный проект и база не важная ни где )

Comment: Можно притвориться, что на хероку production и действовать как с настоящим, но в рамках обучения :)